# Docx4j Permgen Space with 2G and a tiny document when converting to PDF

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, docx4j

We have a 5kb .docx file being read into Docx4j-2.8.1 then converted to a PDF. In a unit test this works but once deployed into Tomcat 7 (TomEE-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT actually) we get Permgen space errors when performing the PDF conversion.

Sample code:

```
wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(inputStream);
final PdfConversion pdfConvertor = new Conversion(wordMLPackage);
pdfConvertor.output(stream, null);
return stream.toByteArray();
```

The inputStream was created from a byte[] of the .docx file. The docx file itself is a single page with only text in Times New Roman and a couple of bullet points (it's for sample use).

The stacktrace is as follows (I have added the heap size to the log at the top):

https://gist.github.com/jmkgreen/5046890

This machine has 6GB of RAM, Tomcat has the following set:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms1536m -Xmx2048M -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"
```

I would not be expecting to see this error. Some advice would be appreciated.

Edit: I added getUsage().getMax() from the MemoryPoolMXBean for Perm Gen right before calling the PDF converter: 82MB.

I have also reduced the tomcat catalina.bat file entry for JAVA_OPTS down to:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"
```

Edit 2: Switching from docx4j to XDocReport solves the crash. Pity neither provide a particularly accurate rendering...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your JAVA_OPTS aren't being read correctly?  The following should be sufficient:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Comment: The options seemed to be read correctly - profiling via Netbeans showed heap space adjusting as expected.